# Converting numbers/strings from one format to another in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm working on a system where certain types of records are represented by identifiers of the form

```
chr17:41222944-41222961
```

where only the numeric characters beginning 41222 are significant (the `chr17` and other characters are, I assume for archiving purposes).

I have a need to manipulate this string in Excel to a string of the form

```
chr17:g.41222944_41222961del
```

Is there a built-in function that can be used to do this? Or would I need to write a VBA routine?

Comment: A "number" starting with `chr17:` isn't a "number", and it's totally unclear to me what "chr17:g.41222944_41222961del" is supposed to represent. Are you asking about how to manipulate a string in Excel, to insert the `g.` and `del` and replace the hyphen with an underscore?

Comment: It represents an ID in a bespoke system I'm working on. There is a number - its starts '4122294441222961' - in there amongst the seemingly arbitary text characters. And yes, I'm asking how to do the string manipulation in Excel, ideally using a built-in function. I built an app for a client in Excel VBA some years previously and I have no desire to do anything like that ever again.

Comment: My confusion is because you're not asking about formatting a number (the fact your string contains digits does not qualify it as a number, just like the fact that 'zlkja;lsj' contains letters does not make it a word). <strike>You should restate your question to be about inserting and replacing content in a string,</strike> (I see you already did), but before doing so I'd definitely do a search first; this has to be one of the most frequent topics asked about here with Excel and VBA.

Comment: You can do it with a combination of `=MID()` and `=REPLACE()` in a nasty formula, but it would be much easier to do in a VBA function that you could just call instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is put a **g.** after the colon, and replace the hyphen with an underscore, and add **del** at the end, then, with your string in A1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,0,"g."),"-","_") & "del"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your function. Write down in a VBA module of an open workbook and then use in Excel as you wish

```
Function reformat(s As String) As String
    reformat = Replace(s, "chr17:", "char17:g.") & "del"
End Function
```